# Java garbage collection in Queue dequeue() sample code

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was going through the code of the implementation of a **Queue** in a course on algorithms and observed the code for *dequeue()* which the author used:

```
private Node first, last;

private class Node {
    String item;
    Node next;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

// Code segment in doubt
public String dequeue() {
    String item = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    if (isEmpty()) last = null;
    return item;
}
```

Here, *first* and *last*, understandably, point to the first and last elements in the queue respectively. I am a bit skeptical about the code in *dequeue()* which the author uses. Since, he is simply doing:

```
first = first.next;
```

without assigning *first.next* to *null*. Will it not leave a dangling reference (or loitering) which will hinder the Garbage Collection mechanism of JVM? I'm a bit confused, shouldn't the code for *dequeue()* look like this instead? (I know for sure that in C/C++ the code should be like below, but want to know the expected behavior of JAVA in this case)

```
public String dequeue() {
    Node old;
    old = first;
    first = first.next;
    old.next = null;
    if (isEmpty()) last = null;
    return old.item;
}
```

I will also appreciate it if someone could point me to a resource which covers this topic in detail with good examples.

Comment: In C++, old = first would call a copy constructor, but in Java, old and first are references to the same object.  So you'd be setting this.first to null, which would mess up the structure for future calls.  But in the original implementation, the original object to which first points no longer has any references to it (assuming queue can only be forward-traversed).  This makes the original first node eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: [Aside], shouldn't `dequeue()` **first** call `isEmpty()`, otherwise a `Null Reference Exception` could occur in the `String item = first.item` call?

Comment: @Kevin I guess you are correct, have to test it out though about the *Null Reference Exception*. I copied the code verbatim out of the slides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `old.next = null` is unnecessary, because `old` is ready to be garbage-collected (the `first = first.next` assignment eliminates its last live reference (once `dequeue` exits)) and so the garbage collector won't trace any of its references.

Comment: What about the reference of the "old.next" to the new "first" which remains. How does the GC know that it has to garbage collect "old" when "old.next" still has a reference to "first"?

Comment: @sultan.of.swing The garbage collector will ignore the `old.next` reference because `old` isn't live. The collector traces the live objects, and so if `old` were live then it would also trace the `old.next` reference; however, `old` is not live (once `dequeue` exits), and so it doesn't matter what references it's holding on to.

Comment: @sultan.of.swing Picture all of the objects in the heap as though they formed a tree (in reality they form a graph, but a tree is easier to visualize). One of the tree's nodes (the "parent" node) is pointing to two "child" nodes. You remove the "parent" from the tree. It isn't necessary to set the parent's "child" references to null, because when the garbage collector traverses the tree it won't traverse the "parent" node because you've removed it from the tree (therefore it is unreachable and isn't live).

Comment: I liked your analogy of objects in the queue as a tree, but what is the actual behavior, how does the GC optimize and know all the live references? How does it maintain the state of all the variables and current references?

Comment: The GC's approach is flipped around from what you think it is.  It doesn't identify _dead_ objects so much as it just deletes everything that isn't live, where "live" is defined as "accessible from the running code."  You should read up on GC implementations for more details, since that's way too complicated to explain in comments.

Comment: @sultan.of.swing The GC begins its trace from the "roots," which are the references that are on the call stack (e.g. the `old` reference is on the call stack, until `dequeue` exits). Usually the garbage collector will do a depth-first traversal of the roots, using mark bits or a bitmap to avoid cycles. When it's finished traversing all live objects, it will then copy those objects to a new sub-heap (if this is a copy collector, e.g. for the young generation of a generational collector), or else it will iterate the heap and delete the dead objects that weren't marked by the traversal

Comment: @sultan.of.swing You seem to be visualizing garbage collection as something akin to [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), where the system continually maintains an up-to-date list of live objects and their references. However, this is much less efficient than a tracing collector, and has problems with collecting cycles in the heap (for example, if an object has a reference to itself, then the reference counting collector will never flag it as being dead).

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot Cool, I like your explanations, can you point me to some resources/links from where I could read up more in depth on these topics?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Can you point me to some good resources/books on this topic?

Comment: @sultan.of.swing The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) is a good place to start.  The best in-depth resource is the [Garbage Collection Handbook](http://amzn.com/1420082795).

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have 2 objects in Queue: A and B

`first` points to `A` and `first.next` points to `B` (in other words `A.next == B`)

The only reference to `A` is `Queue#first` variable. When you do

```
first = first.next; // first == B
```

noone references `A` object anymore, so it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

If your Queue is not implemented as a `Doubly Queue` ( meaning you can access both .Next and .Prev in your queue), then after setting `first` to be `first.next` , there's gonna be no reference or pointer to `first` and then the garbage collection thread will know that it (`first`) needs to be Garbage Collected (Associated memory will be released).

Answer (score 0):

Only references from live objects matter.  These determine which objects are live.

If an object has a reference to a live object, but it is not referenced this will be collected. (The JVM doesn't use reference counts and there is no need to update this)

Another case which concerns people if if two object reference each other (but nothing else does)  Again this is fine because only objects which can accessed from a root node (e.g a Thread) as retained and everything else is collected.